# Lex how to emulate modes or a stack of contexts

Tags: c, lex

I'm trying to figure out how to emulate a context/mode or "stack of contexts" in lex (flex).

In particular, I'd like to write a parser that has a notion of string literals that can drop you back into an expression-y context.

I have a simple grammar that supports raw string literals using the syntax `'...'` and prints a string when it finds one.

However, a string token has potentially unbounded length (up to lex's maximum buffer size which I think is defined in some macro in the generated C source).

I want to define a `begin_string` token `'` and an `end_string` token `'` as well as a distinct token for reading a character while inside a string.

And I want to achieve this by having some notion of a context that says "now I'm in a string" and affects which tokenization rules are "active".

Here's the naive grammar below for context.

```
%{ 

#include <stdio.h>

%}

%option noyywrap

%%

'[^']*' { printf("found string literal (( %s ))\n", yytext); }

\n { /* do nothing */ }
. { /* do nothing */ }

%%

int main()
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html)? If I understand your question, that is what you're looking for (although it's possible that I didn't understand your needs totally). If you use flex, there is no arbitrary limit to a token, by the way; the buffer will be expanded until malloc refuses to provide more space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your needs correctly, that feature is provided with [start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html). As the manual explains, a start condition is a kind of state, which can be used to enable and disable a set of productions.

For example, you might have:

```
%option nodefault
%x IN_STRING

%%
 /* Other patterns for regular tokens */
"'"               { BEGIN(IN_STRING); return BEGIN_STRING; }
<IN_STRING>"'"    { BEGIN(INITIAL);   return END_STRING; }
<IN_STRING>.|\n   {                   return STRING_CHAR; }
```

Flex will optionally enable a feature which allows you to push and pop the current start condition on a stack, but in this simple case that isn't necessary. If you do need to do that, remember to add `%option stack` to your prolog, and read the description of the API at the end of the Start Condition chapter linked above.